# Is it Possible to upload/download files from the Terminal Server Client in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

i need my application to get a file from a Terminal Server Client (my C drive) and move it to the server, is it at all possible to do with .NET?

i can't seem to find any help online. how would i write out the file path?

Comment: Is the drive shared on the server?

Comment: Perhaps you could share your drive to the remote machine and access it that way. In the UI you would edit the connection, select Local Resources tab, More button and share the drive. No idea how you'd do that programmatically, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement support for Terminal Server (now known as Remote Desktop Services) by using the RDS API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015.aspx

Protocol:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also check virtual channels:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx